# Simple Github API request fails

Tags: python, api, github

[image: Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong please ?]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong please ?
`hello-world` from **octocat** is a public repository.

Comment: Print out the calculated URL from which you request and try it out in a browser.

Comment: Please don't post *image* of code. Just post the code as text. This makes it much easier for us to work with.

Comment: Same for output: If it is text show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [octocat/hello-world](https://github.com/octocat/hello-world) project, it has no releases. If you modify your request...

```
r = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases')
```

...you will get back a successful -- but empty -- response.